# Convert data frame into vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a one row/column `dataframe` that I would like to convert into a value.

```
df <- data.table(x=c(300))
>#     x
># 1: 300
```

I've managed to do it by doing this:

```
b <- as.list(df)[[1]]
># [1] 300
```

so that `identical(b, 300) == T`

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? I understand this is a very simple question but I couldn't find a solution. Help?

Comment: well, since turning data.frame's into vector makes sense mostly if you have just one vecor (or eventually if you have all columns of the same type) I think you can just use `df$x` or `df[[1]]` try it : `identical(df$x, 300)` ??

Comment: @mtoto,  unlist doesn't work : u <- unlist(df) ; identical(u,300) returns FALSE

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks. I think `df[[1]]` works well

Comment: @RafaelPereira: yep, but please note the this is not turning a data.frame into a vector (as you asked), but rather turning a column of a data.frame (actually a data.table to be precise) into a vector ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, data frames are lists, so that you can invoke `unlist(df)`.

Comment: It desn't work: `u <- unlist(df) ; identical(u,300)` returns `FALSE`

Comment: It returns false because unlist returns also the names of the columns as vector names...but the values are equal. Try `identical(unname(unlist(df)),300)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `unlist`, you can also simply do:

```
x <- df$x
```

the result is a normal vector with the values from `x`:

```
> x
[1] 300
```